# Can i find the slowest and most frequently query used when working with SQL server in Large transaction log file?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I restored my database from file ( which i received from my co-worker ).
I want to optimize the database performance. So that i want to find the most frequently and the slowest query. or where should i look for ? which tool should i use ?

Comment: Find Most Expensive Queries on SQL Server via this code: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/

Comment: thank you ahmed, i've already used that way. But i want to know that if the .ldf file ( that i restored from the .bak file ) still store the history of the queries that i work with the database before ????

Comment: No. The LDF file stores the history of _changes_ to your database. LDF is of little use for performance tuning. It certainly does not store queries. It stores things like 'change this page to that'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to know that if the .ldf file ( that i restored from the .bak file ) still store the history of the queries that i work with the database before ????

LDF is log file and it won't help you in finding problematic queries

Database cache is not persistent,you can't find problematic queries when you restore database..

There is new technology called [QueryStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn817826.aspx)(staring from 2016),the information stored in query store is persistent across reboots,database restores..

Comment: Thank you so much. I get it now :)